# How to wait ajax data before submit content inside Tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tinymce

I need to update a variable on submit inside tinymce window.

Here the tinymce code:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('tc_button',function(editor,url){
    editor.addButton('tc_button',{
    title: 'Images',

    onclick: function(){
    editor.windowManager.open({
    title: 'Images',
    buttons: [{text: 'Add Shortcode', onclick: 'submit'}, {text: 'Cancel', onclick: 'close'}],

    body: [

    {type: 'container',
    label  : 'Image URL',
    items: [
    {type: 'textbox', id: 'image1', name : 'image1', style:'width:270px'},
    {type: 'listbox', id: 'effect1', name: 'effect1', style:'margin-left:10px'},
    ]}

    ],

    onsubmit: function(e) {


    jQuery.post(ajax_url, 
    {
    action: 'save_image',
    image: imageData,
    }
    ),

    function ( data ){
    var jsonData = tryParseJSON( data );
    if ( jsonData !== false ) {
    var new_url = jsonData.attachment_url;  
    jQuery('#image1').attr('src', new_url);     
    }
    };



    editor.insertContent('[shortcode image1="' + e.data.image1 + '"]' );


    }

    });

    }
    });
    });
```

I need to run `jQuery('#image1').attr('src', new_url)` inside ajax call **before** `editor.insertContent` is added inside editor. How can i set it so to wait ajax call is ended and `#image1` source is updated with ajax result value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you put `editor.insertContent(...)` inside the callback ?

Comment: I tryed it but 'editor.insertContent' not works. No shortcode is added.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **editor.insertContent('[shortcode image1="' + e.data.image1 + '"]' );** inside call back function after **jQuery('#image1').attr('src', new_url);**

```
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('tc_button', function(editor, url) {
    editor.addButton('tc_button', {
        title: 'Images',

        onclick: function() {
            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'Images',
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Add Shortcode',
                    onclick: 'submit'
                }, {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    onclick: 'close'
                }],

                body: [

                    {
                        type: 'container',
                        label: 'Image URL',
                        items: [{
                                type: 'textbox',
                                id: 'image1',
                                name: 'image1',
                                style: 'width:270px'
                            },
                            {
                                type: 'listbox',
                                id: 'effect1',
                                name: 'effect1',
                                style: 'margin-left:10px'
                            },
                        ]
                    }

                ],

                onsubmit: function(e) {


                    jQuery.post(ajax_url, {
                            action: 'save_image',
                            image: imageData,
                        }),

                        function(data) {
                            var jsonData = tryParseJSON(data);
                            if (jsonData !== false) {
                                var new_url = jsonData.attachment_url;
                                jQuery('#image1').attr('src', new_url);
                            }
                            editor.insertContent('[shortcode image1="' + e.data.image1 + '"]');
                        };
                }

            });

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I did it but on submit button, tinymce window is closed, ajax call is fine processed and in wp tinymce editor no shortcode is added.